# check the form array values using ngIf within the FormArray

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to show the button view in-order to change the type of answer using a selection box. The **QuestionType** value has been changing but by using *ngIF it will not show the right button view in the browser.
It is placed within the form array of Reactive Forms module.

Here is the code:

```html
<ng-container formArrayName="AnswersList">
  <tr *ngFor="let itemrows of itemrow.controls.AnswersList.controls; let ansi=index" [formGroupName]="ansi">
    <td *ngIf="SurveyForm.controls.Questions.controls.QuestionType==2">
      <mat-checkbox [disabled]="true"></mat-checkbox>
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="SurveyForm.controls.Questions.controls.QuestionType==1">
      <mat-radio-group [disabled]="true">
        <mat-radio-button value="1"></mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </td>
    <td style="width:100%;">
      <input matInput placeholder="Enter an answer choice" formControlName="Answer" class="td_radio_button" *ngIf="open_input_choice" required>
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="itemrow.controls.AnswersList.controls.length>1">
      <i class="material-icons" style="position: absolute;right:60px;margin-top:-13px;cursor: pointer;" (click)="removeAnswers(itemrow,ansi)">remove_circle_outline</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Please provide a suggestion on how to solve this: Plnkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/SWjYmV9d8LLDMc1V58iZ?p=preview

---

Comment: can you explain yourself better?

Comment: display the check box or radio button based on selection of single choice or multiple choice using selection box in the Reactive Forms Module. You can access the code through the plunkr.